# skimage imread fails to load jpoed images

Tags: python

I am trying to read a jpeg image using skimage. But i am getting the following error. I have installed dependent libjpeg under /usr/local

```
#Import libraries for doing image analysis
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize


image = imread("/root/ObjectClass/train/99938.jpg", as_grey=True)

S

    park assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/ObjectClass/OC.py", line 6, in <module>
        image = imread("/root/ObjectClass/train/99938.jpg", as_grey=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scikit_image-0.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/skimage/io/_io.py", line 100, in imread
        img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scikit_image-0.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 207, in call_plugin
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scikit_image-0.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py", line 52, in imread
        raise ValueError('Could not load "%s"\nPlease see documentation at: %s' % (fname, site))
    ValueError: Could not load "/root/ObjectClass/train/99938.jpg"
    Please see documentation at: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, pil_plugin.py (line 52) raises an error because the following two calls failed.

```
im = Image.open(fname) 
im.getdata()[0]
```

So, it's in fact the problem of PIL. Try re-install PIL to solve this problem.

```
sudo pip uninstall PIL
sudo pip install PIL
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on a malformed jpg -- it seems the file was not saved correctly and was in some way corrupt.  I noticed an error to this effect when I tried to open the jpg in GIMP.